# Joomla template update gives error

Tags: templates, joomla

Today I tried to update one of my templates for Joomla 2.5. I was always getting the following error:

```
There is already a Template using the named directory: Install.
Are you trying to install the same template again?
```

When I delete the template and install it again, this problem does not appear. What is causing this error and how can I update the template without deleting it first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to add `method="upgrade"` to the template declaration:

In my `templateDetails.xml` make sure that the line looks like this:

```
<extension version="2.5" type="template" client="site" method="upgrade">
```

Without the `method="upgrade"` the template must always be uninstalled then reinstalled when it needs to be upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

Go to extensions > extensions manager and on the manage tab, make sure you select the template in question and hit uninstall. Then just reinstall it.

I was getting that error or a similar one, because I deleted my template instead of unistalling it.

Comment: That's the whole point of using `method="upgrade"`, it saves having to uninstall then reinstall again

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading a Joomla 1.5 template to Joomla 2.5
https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Upgrading_a_Joomla_1.5_template_to_Joomla_2.5

Migrating a Template from Joomla 1.5 to 3.x
https://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_a_Template_from_Joomla_1.5_to_3.x